# How the php://input was made reusable in 5.6

Tags: php

In the PHP's [documentations](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) 
it says that the `php://input` was made reusable in 5.6, what does it mean?

Do I need any changes to my current codes that use `php://input`, in order to be compatible with php 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate note in the same [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input).

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

Therefore you should not have any problems with PHP 5.6